# $3$-ranks of elliptic curves and representations $p=ax^3+by^3$

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

Let $p$ be a prime with $p\equiv2\pmod3$ and $E_p$ the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+9p^2$
which has a rational $3$-torsion point. Let $\alpha$ from $E_p(\mathbb Q)$ to $\mathbb Q^*/{\mathbb Q^*}^3$ be the $3$-descent map such that generically $\alpha(P)=y-3p$.
Assuming a weak form of BSD (parity) the image of $\alpha$ has cardinality $3$ or $27$, and
the following six conditions are equivalent:

(1) Cardinality of image of $\alpha$ is $27$.

(2) The rank of $E$ is $2$.

(3) $p=x^3+6y^3$

(4) $p=2x^3+3y^3$

(5) $p=4x^3+12y^3$

(6) $p=9x^3+18y^3$

always with $x$, $y$ in $\mathbb Q$. My question is this: can one prove the equivalence of
(3), (4), (5), and (6) without assuming BSD ? There may be a completely elementary way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

just a computer search for small primes, with bounds prescribed for $x,y$  It slowed way down, and you can see that I found just three representations for prime 617,  considerably bigger bounds would be needed to finish that one. Plenty of primes $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ did not allow any of the four representation with fairly small bounds on $x, y.$ I edited out those primes by hand.

Each prime is printed, then the next four lines are i the form

A+B x y D
which means 
$$ |A x^3 + B y^3| = p D^3 $$

```
2
 2+3  1   0  1
 4+12  1   1  2
 1+6  2   -1  1
 9+18  2   -1  3


5
 4+12  1   -3  4
 9+18  1   -2  3
 1+6  1   -1  1
 2+3  1   1  1



41
 4+12  1   3  2
 9+18  5   -1  3
 1+6  7   -4  1
 2+3  52   1  19


47
 1+6  1   -2  1
 2+3  4   -3  1
 9+18  5   2  3
 4+12  67   -41  20


83
 9+18  1   -5  3
 2+3  1   3  1
 4+12  11   -1  4
 1+6  67   -38  7



131
 2+3  4   1  1
 1+6  5   1  1
 4+12  7   -3  2
 9+18  97   -77  3


173
 1+6  5   2  1
 4+12  7   1  2
 9+18  17   -13  3
 2+3  73   -51  13




227
 9+18  7   -8  3
 4+12  47   35  16
 2+3  224   -1047  247
 1+6  299   -16  49




311
 2+3  7   -5  1
 9+18  49   -8  15
 4+12  227   105  58
 1+6  683   -425  77



359
 2+3  2   -5  1
 4+12  7   5  2
 9+18  29   -43  15
 1+6  41   -45  11


383
 1+6  1   -4  1
 9+18  5   8  3
 4+12  61   -39  8
 2+3  76   -23  13

401
 9+18  11   -4  3
 2+3  13   -11  1
 1+6  55   -37  7
 4+12  511   -3  110

443
 9+18  11   -1  3
 4+12  25   -17  2
 1+6  53   8  7
 2+3  556   -987  179

449
 9+18  11   2  3
 1+6  49   -27  1
 2+3  79   5  13
 4+12  1129   2015  614

503
 2+3  4   5  1
 4+12  103   -2119  610
 9+18  295   -209  51
 1+6  2015   453  259

509
 1+6  5   4  1
 2+3  29   -73  13
 9+18  307   -173  69
 4+12  739   -1683  478

617
 2+3  31   -101  17
 4+12  41   -27  4
 9+18  61   13  15
-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Once you've found representations for any two of the four cubics,
you can get the other two using the group law on the elliptic curve.
For $p=617$ this yields $37607^3 + 6 \cdot 18247^3 = 5257^3 p$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies that is so nice.  It seems pretty rare that the program gave only one of the representations.

Comment: Eventually you will see cases where only one of the four cubics
has a representation within your search limits, and also more $p$ for which
you find solutions for two or three but the other(s) is/are out of range
(though still accessible via the group law, as happened for $p=617$).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately i am constrained by the situation to deliver a *negative* answer.
(As it often happens in life, it may be harder to fix the framework and disprove, then to claim and prove.)
Because of this nature of the answer, i took the decision to give first examples move (in general) the problem inside $E^p(\Bbb Q)$,
and illustrate there inside an equivalent situation.

Passing for instance [ from (3) to construct a solution for (4) ] is equivalent to [ starting with one point of infinite order in
$E^p(\Bbb Q)$ i.e. the algebraic rank is $\ge 1$ and showing it is $\ge 2$, i.e. finding a further independent point ].

Finally, there will be some claims of positive related structural facts.

---

Let us experiment with $p$ among $1979$, $1997$, $2003$.

Let $E(a,b,p)$ the curve given by the affine equation
$$
E(a,b,p)\ :\ ax^3+by^3=p\ .
$$
In all considered $(a,b)$-cases we will have $36ab=d^3$, for some $d\in\Bbb Q$. Let us record the possible cases in a table:
$$
\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|l|}
\hline
a & b  & c &  d & \text{case in OP}\\\hline\hline
1 & 6  & p &  6 & (3) \\\hline
2 & 3  & p &  6 & (4) \\\hline
4 & 12 & p & 12 & (5) \\\hline
9 & 18 & p & 18 & (6) \\\hline
\end{array}
$$

There is a map

- from $E(a,b,p)$ : $ax^3+by^3=p$
- to  $E^p$ : $Y^2=X^3+9p^2$,

which is defined on rational points $(x,y)=\in E(a,b,p)(\Bbb Q)$ by
$$
\begin{aligned}
(x,y)&\to (X,Y):=\Big(\ -ab\; xy\ ,\ 3(ax^3-by^3)\ \Big)\ ,\\
X &= -d\;xy\ ,\\
Y &= 3(ax^3-by^3)\ ,\\[3mm]
x &= +\left(\frac 1{2a}\left(-\frac Y3+p\right)\right)^{1/3}\ ,\\
y &= -\left(\frac 1{2b}\left(-\frac Y3-p\right)\right)^{1/3}\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
The sum of the two numbers $ax^3$ and $-by^3$ is $\frac Y3$,
their product is $\frac {X^3}{36}$, so the two numbers are in all considered cases the roots of the equation in $T$
$$
T^2 -\frac Y3T+\frac{X^3}{36}=0\ .
$$
(These are my "human choices", very uncomfortable for the study of each $E(a,b,c)$ alone, but made to put all cases (3), (4), (5), (6) in a common hat. For instance the above equation in $T$ does not depend on $a,b$, so it is better suited as an intermediate between the cases.) Let us check:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Y^2 &= 9(ax^3-by^3)^2
\\
&= 9(ax^3+by^3)^2-36ab\; x^3y^3
\\
&= 9(ax^3+by^3)^2+d^3\; x^3y^3
\\
&= 9p^2+X^3
\end{aligned}
$$

---

At this point i will start an experiment first, then relate the obtained solutions to the question.

It is clear that each $(x,y)$ from one of the cases (3) to (6) induces a $\Bbb Q$-rational point $(X,Y)$ on $E^p$,
but conversely, taking one $\Bbb Q$-rational point $(X,Y)$ on $E^p$ does not induce an $(x,y)$ back,
except for the case where we can extract the cubic root.
This happens at most once, since $a$ must be $\frac 12\left(-\frac Y3+p\right)$ modulo cubes to insure $x\in\Bbb Q$.
(And if this is the case, the cubic root for $y$ gives rise to a $y\in\Bbb Q$.)

Consider the [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) code *Code 1* at the end of this answer.

It gives solutions of $x^3+6y^3=2003$ only for $R$ of the shape $R=Q+(3mP+3nQ)\in Q+3E^p(\Bbb Q)$,
where $P,Q$ are the sage choice of the free part generators for $E^p(\Bbb Q)$.

We change slightly the code adapted to fit $p$ and  $a,b,d$ covering the other cases that are relevant,
and the results are condensed in the following table:
$$
\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & b  & p    &  \text{equation} &d & \text{case} & R\text{ mod }3E^p(\Bbb Q) & \alpha(R)\\\hline\hline
1 & 6  & 2003 &  x^3 +  6y^3 = 2003 &  6 & (3) &    2Q & 1/6\\\hline
2 & 3  & 2003 & 2x^3 +  3y^3 = 2003 &  6 & (4) &     P & 2/3\\\hline
4 & 12 & 2003 & 4x^3 + 12y^3 = 2003 & 12 & (5) &  2P+Q & 4/12\\\hline
9 & 18 & 2003 & 9x^3 + 18y^3 = 2003 & 18 & (6) &   P+Q & 9/18\\\hline\hline
%
1 & 6  & 1997 &  x^3 +  6y^3 = 1997 &  6 & (3) &  2P+Q & 1/6\\\hline
2 & 3  & 1997 & 2x^3 +  3y^3 = 1997 &  6 & (4) &    2Q & 2/3\\\hline
4 & 12 & 1997 & 4x^3 + 12y^3 = 1997 & 12 & (5) &     P & 4/12\\\hline
9 & 18 & 1997 & 9x^3 + 18y^3 = 1997 & 18 & (6) &   P+Q & 9/18\\\hline\hline
%
1 & 6  & 1979 &  x^3 +  6y^3 = 1979 &  6 & (3) &    P + T & 1/6\\\hline
2 & 3  & 1979 & 2x^3 +  3y^3 = 1979 &  6 & (4) &  P+Q + T & 2/3\\\hline
4 & 12 & 1979 & 4x^3 + 12y^3 = 1979 & 12 & (5) & P+2Q + T & 4/12\\\hline
9 & 18 & 1979 & 9x^3 + 18y^3 = 1979 & 18 & (6) &    Q     & 9/18\\\hline
%
\end{array}
$$
Here $\alpha$ is the $3$-descent morphism mentioned in the OP mapping
a (generic) point $R(X,Y)\in E^p(\Bbb Q)$ to $(Y-3p)$ modulo cubes in the set generated multiplicatively by $2,3,p$ of cardinality $3^3=27$.
(For $T=(0,3p)$ the expression $Y-3p$ is "bad", not in $\Bbb Q^\times$, but we set $\alpha(T)$ to be the inverse of $\alpha(-T)=\alpha((0,-3p))=-3p-3p=-6p$.
So $2\cdot 3\cdot p$ is always in the image of $\alpha$. To have full possible image, we will deal with $\langle 2,3\rangle$ inside $\Bbb Q^\times $
modulo cubes, exactly hat happens in the OP.)

In all cases (3) to (6) we have
correspondingly
$$
\alpha(R)=6b=\frac ab\text{ modulo cubes .}
$$
$R(X,Y)$ is here the point obtained from $(x,y)$ with $ax^3+by^3=p$ via the above map $(x,y)\to(X,Y)$.

The relation to the $3$-Selmer-group is transparent.

---

Discussion of the experimental results.

If we start with $p=2003$ and a special solution for (3),
we have equivalently found a point of the shape $Q+3(?)$ on $E^p(\Bbb Q)$.
So we have only one point of infinite order on a curve that (conjecturally) should have rank two.

*Can we construct with only this information (algorithmically) an other independent point?*

Then we would use the $3$-descent mophism  $\alpha$ and get points for the other cases (4), (5), (6), and conversely,
each point for the cases (4), (5), (6) gives a further independent point.)
This is a highly complex arithmetical task still, and although it is "only half of the work",
i don't have / see a construction.
(This is only my fault caused by the missing arithmetical education during all that operator algebra efforts,
but from this subjective perspective, i would claim that...)

The answer to the question is from this (constructive) point of view *negative*.

---

This state of the art is of course not satisfactory, i will try to insert also some *positive* statements related to the OP.

Consider all values in $G=\langle 2,3\rangle\subset\Bbb Q^\times$ modulo cubes.
We obtain a multiplicative group isomorphic to the additive group $(\Bbb Z/3,+)^2\cong \Bbb F_3^2$,
and the last incarnation is (enriched to) a vector space over $\Bbb F_3$ in a "box"
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 2^2\\\hline
3 & 2\cdot 3 & 2^2\cdot 3\\\hline
3^2 & 2\cdot 3^2 & 2^2\cdot 3^2\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
We make the following choices of tuples $(a,b)$ in a corresponding "box":
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
- & (9,18) & (18,9)\\\hline
(4,12) & (1,6) & (2,3)\\\hline
(12,4) & (3,2) & (6,1)\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
*Proposition:* Let $(a,b)$ and $(a',b')$ be two tuples, corresponding to a basis of  $G$, seen as $\Bbb F^2_3$.
Assume we have rational points $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ on $E(a,b,p)$ and $E(a',b',p)$.

Then we have rational points for all tuples mentioned in the eight entries above.
(And $E^p$ has rank two and the image of $\alpha$ is the full group $\langle2,3,p\rangle$ with $27$ elements.)

*Short proof:* $\alpha$ is a morphism.

$\square$

---

A detailed version of this is as follows:

*Proof:*
Let $R(X,Y)$, $R'(X',Y')$ be the images of the two points  in $E^p(\Bbb Q)$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\alpha(R)
&=
Y-3p\\
&=3(ax^3-by^3)-3p\\
&=3(ax^3+by^3-p)-6by^3\\
&=-6by^3\\
&\equiv 6b\equiv \frac ab\text{ modulo cubes}
\end{aligned}
$$
in all our cases. (The last equivalence because of $36ab=d^3$.)

Similarly $\alpha(R')=a'/b'$.
These two values $a/b$ and $a'/b'$ are linearly independent seen in $\Bbb F_3^2$ as assumed,
so all other eight (non-trivial) values in the above "box"$\cong \Bbb F_3^2$ can be reached
as a non-trivial linear combination with coefficients $0$ and $\pm 1$. In case of a $-1$ coefficient,
replace the corresponding point $R(X,Y)$ or $R'(X',Y')$ by its opposite, $-R$, respectively $-R'$. We pass from $(a,b)$ and/or respectively $(a',b')$
to $(b,a)$ and/or respectively $(b',a')$.
The corresponding values $(a/b)^{\pm 1}$, $(a'/b')^{\pm 1}$ are also a basis, when seen in $\Bbb F_3^2$, so we can reduce the
analyzis to the case when the linear combination has coefficients $0$ and $1$.
The only case remained to be studied is $R+R'$.
(This above reduction is not necessary, but for the typist the $\pm 1$ choices in $\pm R\pm R'$ are now no longer needed.)
Then $\alpha(R+R')=(a/b)(a'/b')=(aa')/(bb')$ corresponds to a tuple $(A,B)$ in the above "box", $(aa')/(bb')=A/B$ modulo cubes.

From $\alpha(R+R')=A/B=6B$ modulo cubes, we see that the $Y$-component $Y''$ of the point $R+R'=(X'',Y'')$ insures the cubic root occuring in
$$
y''
=\left(\frac 12\left(\frac Y3-p\right)\right)^{1/3}
=\left(\frac 16(\frac Y-3p)\right)^{1/3}
$$
lands in $\Bbb Q$, associate then the corresponding $x''\in \Bbb Q$, so that we have a solution
$(x'', y'')$ for the equation of the tuple $(A,B)$ .

This completes the proof.

$\square$

---

As a consequence, we see that any *two* properties among (3), (4), (5), (6) imply all properties (1) to (6).

With the same argument, either (1) or (2) imply all (3), (4), (5), (6).

Without further work, this is all that can be said.

---

*Note:* If we start with one point $(x,y)$ satisfying (3), say, than let $R$ be the induced point $E^p(\Bbb Q)$.
We can build in $E^p(\Bbb Q)$ all points $R+3NR$, then lift them back to points satisfying (3).
We get thus from one point $(x,y)$ countable number of points, so the equation (3) defines
an elliptic curve of rank at least one. We need more to "produce an other point" (of a different nature).

*Note:* In the case $p=1979$, the generators of the free part of $E^p(\Bbb Q)$ are as follows:

```
sage: P, Q = EllipticCurve([0, 9*1979^2]).gens()
sage: Q.xy()
(-272, 3889)
sage: P.xy()
(-18216695/66564, 65958267131/17173512)
```

I see no "simple argument" (in both theory and in practice) to produce the above `P`, having only the knowledge of `Q = (-272, 3889)`.

*Note:* Trying to move the scene inside of the arithmetic of a number field is also a complicated story.
The fields $\Bbb Q(6^{1/3})$, $\Bbb Q(2^{1/3}, 3^{1/3})$ have class number one. (See the appended *Code 2*.)
We have a concrete description of their units. But the problem of realizing the norm $p$ in two ways that differ in their nature is the same one.
For instance, with $a=6^{1/3}$ and $p=1979$ we find an element of norm $p$ by factorizing in $\Bbb Q(a)$ the $\Bbb Q$-prime $1979$ as
$$
p=(337 + 150a + 102a^2) \; (11 + 6a -6a^2)\ .
$$
The factor $(11+6a-6a^2)$ has norm $1979$. One solution to our problem (corresponding to a number field element written with missing $a^2$ part) is
$$
\frac 1{35}(-263+258a)\ .
$$
It is now a non-trivial process to find further solutions (missing $a^2$ part) using units and elements with cubic norm.

---

*Code 1:*

```
def my_cubic_root(a):
    """a is in QQ, if it is a cube, we return a^(1/3) in QQ, else None.
    Needed since we have problems with bool((-27)^(1/3) in QQ)..."""
    if a == 0:    return 0
    sign, p, q = 1, a.numerator(), a.denominator()
    if p < 0:    sign, p = -1, -p
    pp, qq = p^(1/3), q^(1/3)
    if pp in QQ and qq in QQ:    return sign * QQ(pp) / QQ(qq)

p = 2003
E = EllipticCurve([0, 9*p^2])
P, Q = E.gens()
T = E.point( (0, 3*p) )
a, b = 1, 6    # first case in the table
d = QQ( (36*a*b)^(1/3) )

J = [-8..8]
for m, n, k in cartesian_product([J, J, [0,1,2]]):
    R = m*P + n*Q + k*T
    if R == E.point(0):
        continue
    X, Y = R.xy()
    s, t = (Y/3 + p)/2,  (Y/3 - p)/2
    x = my_cubic_root(s/a)
    if x:    # then x in QQ and x is not zero
        y = my_cubic_root(-t/b)    # and then also y in QQ
        # x, y have possibly a big gcd, we want to print...
        # so it may seem better to force integer numbers...
        LCM = lcm( x.denominator(), y.denominator() )
        x0, y0, z0 = x*LCM, y*LCM, LCM
        print(f"R = {m}P + {n}Q + {k}T\nx = {x0}\ny = {y0}\nz = {z0}\n")
```

This delivers a long list of some points $R=(X,Y)\in E^p(\Bbb Q)$ ($R=mP+nQ+kT$ with $-8\le m,n\le 8$ found in terms of the sage-generators $P,Q$ and the $T$ torsion point) for which we get back a solution $(x,y)$. Here is a very small part of the long list...

```
R = 0P + -7Q + 0T
x = 25436545507617451806991358756909219533477638105712374213846397555195879982437905172639534240075646580404902724011380073423114348849619768865347595418688900649922166546243453830769840933
y = 8670782032048955321129903281080010960645348316159791215455141268018661461219887281802896500458956709284909948105938453014382939187977502562188660147114609049623362562200245401625880031
z = 2166529709517764006897615049800738288846177073891261914077119796463740061635879465681855349469378188013181189812878489256239707989996792109243772929949155694651080013613238673253020821

R = 0P + -4Q + 0T
x = -1248383626448011320864639335968278987254059481029611805066801
y = 892745013130488404006175343285917721481004636409866227451640
z = 105072279642502359685014789309113123529012318539767007228077

R = 0P + -1Q + 0T
x = 5593
y = -1969
z = 401

R = 0P + 2Q + 0T
x = 466195724755957
y = 598800679557740
z = 88525032724511

R = 0P + 5Q + 0T
x = -12730202841795146665456659465095899487115785453015815852478856082252223469530919315332698381397
y = 7018071224223599750845585053528881247631263458296145320784676818035645960426486076253452910281
z = 176150641790808140253477784349063183165963304192648709822885554148067212479172504836399445931
```

---

*Code 2:*

```
sage: R.<x> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
sage: K.<a> = NumberField(x^3-6)
sage: K.class_number()
1
sage: L.<b,c> = NumberField( [x^3-2, x^3-6] )
sage: L.class_number()
1

sage: xi = (-263 + 258*a)/35
sage: xi.norm()
1979

sage: K(1979).factor()
(102*a^2 + 150*a + 337) * (-6*a^2 + 6*a + 11)
sage: (11 + 6*a - 6*a^2).norm()
1979
```